# CSS/JQuery Hover Affect Only Hovered Element and Not Parent

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a list of nested items, each which has it's own edit link.

```
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>
    Fruits <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Banana <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
        <li>Orange <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
        <li>
            Apple <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a>
            <ul>
                <li>Fuji <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
                <li>Red Delicious <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
                <li>Golden <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    Drinks <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Coke <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
        <li>Pepsi <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Something <a href="#" class="editLink">Edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

I only want the edit link to display when one hovers over list element.
Currently when I hover on a child element, the parent is affected as well.

```
$('li').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.editLink').show();
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.editLink').hide();   
    }
);
```

I have the following CSS to make the edit link hidden initially

```
.editLink{
    display:none;
}
```

How do I make it so that only the hovered element has the edit link show and not the others?
Seems like the hide part is fine but the show part affects all the nested parents.
Here is the sample in action: http://jsfiddle.net/D7yWm/

Comment: You could use mouseenter and mouseleave events, and consume them in the child, so as not to propagate the event to parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try. It uses the direct child selector (http://jsfiddle.net/D7yWm/4/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').hover(
        function(ev){
            var li = $(this);
            li.parents('li').find('>.editLink').hide();
            if ( ! li.find('li > .editLink:visible').length ) {
                li.find('>.editLink').show();
            }
        },
        function(){
            var li = $(this);
            li.find('>.editLink').hide();
            li.parents('li:first').find('>.editLink').show();
        }
    );
});
```

If you want it localized to just the text, you're going to have to wrap the text in a `<span>` or something and use that instead.

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

And if that doesn't work for you, you may have to look at a different way of adding the bullets. Or use this as a starting point for figuring the rest out...

Comment: Seems to almost work. If you hover from top to bottom it works. But if you hover from bottom to top, when hovering the last child element, the parents are affected

Comment: Almost...what's weird is if you hover over the bullets, the parent is affected

Comment: Updated the CSS to move the bullet position inside, though I wasn't seeing your issue anyhow (using Chrome).

Comment: I think the issue is when you hover to the left of the bullet on any child element, you are technically hovering over the parent, and that's when the parent edit link is displaying.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the bit about having to use a span if you want it specific. Either that or remove the padding/margins from the `<ul>` and add padding to the `<li>`s. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D7yWm/5/

Answer (score 2):

You need stop propagation of the event in the handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li').hover(
      function(e){
         e.stopPropagation();
           $(this).find('.editLink').show();
      },
      function(){
           $(this).find('.editLink').hide();   
      }
   );
});
```

Comment: This almost worked except when a parent is hovered, it hovers all the children.

Answer (score 2):

If you want parent's `.editlink` to hide after you move from them to their children then you can use this:

```
$('li').hover(
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parents('li').trigger('mouseleave');
        $(this).children('.editLink').show();
    },
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parents('li').trigger('mouseleave');
        $(this).children('.editLink').hide();
    }
);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/FzjRW/)

Comment: The edit link for Coffee is not coming up. And the parent edit link comes up only half the time for some reason. I am hovering them both from top to bottom and bottom to top.

Comment: Works except when you hover from a child to its parent

Comment: There is no editlink for coffee. I'll look into that child->parent thing and hopefully solve it

Comment: Can't be done that way, since when you go from a child to a parent, you don't hover the parent again (you're already inside it), and you already triggered mouseleave for the parent.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the same as your problem but it may help somebody else. The idea is to highlight the top hovered child without affecting the parents below: http://jsfiddle.net/skibulk/mcq6Lvw3/6/

```
$("div").hover(
    function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('active').parents().removeClass('active');
    },
    function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('active').parent().addClass('active');
    }
);
```

Comment: the `e.stopPropagation()` worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<li>`'s are nested inside eachother, the parents are still being "hovered" when you hover over a child. To prevent all the parent links showing, you can loop through all the parent `<li>`'s and hide the links for the parents. Also, use `.children()` to only select a direct child, not nested children.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).parents('li').each(function(){$(this).children('.editLink').hide();});
            $(this).children('.editLink').show();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.editLink').hide();   
        }
    );
});
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdmgM/).

Comment: This almost worked. It seems to work when you are hovering from top to bottom. But if you hover from bottom to top, the parent is still affected.