# adding a class to child then it effecting on parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add class in all element which on i hovers. but I am using the jquery code. but when i hover on any element class is automatically added in all parents can any one suggest that how can i add class in element which i actually hovered.

my js code is

```
$(AllTags).mouseover(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('g-hovered');
});
$(AllTags).mouseenter(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).removeClass('g-hovered');
});

var AllTags = "div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video,article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section "
```

I dont want to pass any specific class and tag.

Comment: y do u need jquery for it, you can do it via CSS classname:hover

Comment: I want to add class in any tag which i hover

Comment: i want to achieve that on which tag i will hover the g-hovered class will be added to that element not in the parent tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS/JQuery Hover Affect Only Hovered Element and Not Parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981405/css-jquery-hover-affect-only-hovered-element-and-not-parent)

Comment: If any body have no answer and not like any answer than please dont down point any answer. you can give down point to my question but please down point to any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle. Is this what you are wanting to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/k398G/5/

```
var allTags = "div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video,article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section";

$(allTags).on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('g-hovered');
});
```

Comment: grate job. I have modified the function and used $(allTags).on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
   $(allTags).removeClass('g-hovered');
    $(this).addClass('g-hovered');
});

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it is done with javascript: [Demo](http://jsbin.com/samirine/6/)

```
  var allTags = ['div', 'span', 'applet', 'object', 'iframe','h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'address', 'big', 'cite', 'code','del', 'dfn', 'em', 'img', 'ins', 'kbd', 'q', 's', 'samp','small', 'strike', 'strong', 'sub', 'sup', 'tt', 'var','b', 'u', 'i', 'center','dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'ol', 'ul', 'li','fieldset', 'form', 'label', 'legend','table', 'caption', 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'thead', 'tr', 'th', 'td','article', 'aside', 'canvas', 'details', 'embed', 'figure', 'figcaption', 'footer', 'header', 'hgroup', 'menu', 'nav', 'output', 'ruby', 'section', 'summary','time', 'mark', 'audio', 'video','article', 'aside', 'details', 'figcaption', 'figure', 'footer', 'header', 'hgroup', 'menu', 'nav', 'section'];
```

`var j=0;

 window.onmouseover = function() {
                change();
            };



 function classAdd(element) {
      return function() { element.setAttribute('class','first');
                     };
          }

 function classRemove(element) {
       return function() { element.removeAttribute('class','first');  
              };
           }  

 function change() {

      for (var i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) {

        var element=document.getElementsByTagName(allTags[i]);

          for (j=0;j<element.length;j++) {
            element[j].onmouseover = classAdd(element[j]);

            element[j].onmouseout = classRemove(element[j]);
                                   }
                        } 
               }`