# Jquery hover child, negate parent hover effects

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a lot of code so doing this manually isn't feasible, but when any element is hovered over I need it to scale in size. Obviously it's not hard with css, but I had some issues when a child element is hovered the parent element hover state remains. So if the child was hovered, the parent and child would both be scaled up. Using jquery it wouldn't be hard for a specific child and parent but its not possible to write code for each parent and child element.

What I am asking is, is there a way using jquery to make it so on any element hovered it adds css but also when hovering of a child removes the parent hover effect. So if child is hovered over, the parent hover effect is removed. Adblock does this. A gif explains what I mean - https://gyazo.com/c9348ba943cace723e569e4ace69dd62

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981405/css-jquery-hover-affect-only-hovered-element-and-not-parent

Answer (score 2):

This code worked wonders

```
$("div").hover(
function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('active').parents().removeClass('active');
},
function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('active').parent().addClass('active');
}
);
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32492163/6677578